# When will be the input for TFRecord in TFX released?

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

The current released TFX only contains the csv_input function. I am dealing with images data, and trying to use the input for TFRecord. I have seen it in the github code, so wandering how soon it will be in the released version of TFX? Or is there any ways to work around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe TFRecord is planned to be released in 0.14 release. In the meantime, have you tried installing from source or building wheel from source and install?

Check out import_example_gen component on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/tfx/components/example_gen/import_example_gen/component.py) that has implementation for TFRecord input for TFX pipelines.